# mount multiple ext4 partitions manually

Tags: linux, mount, adoptable-storage, ext4

I have rooted android phone running android 10. I have one ext4 partition created using :

```
  #  dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/ext1.img bs=1M count=1024
  #  mkfs.ext4 -F /sdcard/ext1.img
```

which I mount using below commands:

```
  #  mknod    /dev/block/loop52  b 7 0 
  #  losetup  /dev/block/loop52  /sdcard/ext1.img
  #  mkdir /mnt/ext
  #  mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime  /dev/block/loop52  /mnt/ext
```

`ext1.img` file gets mounted successfully but when I create another ext4 file and try to mount in `/mnt/ext2` using following commands. It gets mounted but the contents of `ext1.img` are shown in `/mnt/ext2`.

```
  #  mknod    /dev/block/loop62  b 7 0 
  #  losetup  /dev/block/loop62  /sdcard/ext2.img
  #  mkdir /mnt/ext2
  #  mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime  /dev/block/loop62  /mnt/ext2
```

What changes do I need to make to mount multiple ext4 files in android ?

Comment: You are using the same minor number for both devices. Second time you should do `mknod /dev/block/loop62 b 7 1`. But why are you doing `mknod` and `losetup` manually? Mostly devices have already a few (usually 8) loop devices created on boot (which you might be overwriting by using the same major/minor numbers). And `mount` command handles `losetup` on its own. Just do `mkdir <mount_point>; mount <img_file> <mount_point>`.

Comment: Using `mknod /dev/block/loop62 b 7 1`. then ` losetup  /dev/block/loop62  /sdcard/ext.img` gives error: `losetup: /dev/block/loop62=/sdcard/ext2.img: Bad file descriptor`.     Aren't those loop devices (created on boot) used by the system itself ?  Running `mount  /sdcard/ext2.img /mnt/ext2`  shows error: `mount: can't setup loop device: No such device or address`

Comment: Which `losetup` and `mount` binaries are you using? `busybox`, `toybox`, standalone? Share `strace` of both commands. Also do `ls -l /dev/block/loop*` and `grep -H . /sys/block/loop*/loop/backing_file`.

Comment: The problem is solved. I used the existing system `/dev/block/loop*`  i.e. `/dev/block/loop0` and `/dev/block/loop1`.  Then mounted both ext4 files using :  `losetup  /dev/block/loop0  /sdcard/ext.img ; mkdir /mnt/ext ; mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime  /dev/block/loop0  /mnt/ext` ;  `losetup  /dev/block/loop1  /sdcard/ext2.img ; mkdir /mnt/ext2 ; mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime  /dev/block/loop1  /mnt/ext2` .